# How to unify js validation scripts

Tags: javascript, css, validation, input, unification

So I have several jquery scripts that I can use as an basic form of immediate input validation.  Each script adds/removes a .preventclick .valid or .invalid class onto the input field forcing a color change of the border(red/green).  Each script also causes the submit button to either fadein, fadeout or add the .preventclick class based upon the validity of the input field.  My form of 7 input fields are all on one long scrolling page with a submit button on the bottom

So each individual script works as intended, when I use all the different types of validation scripts they work as intended on the input field but the fadein/fadeout of the submit button does not work as intended. If all of the inputs are valid and you change two to be invalid the submit button will disappear as intended, but when you then make one of those two invalid inputs valid the fadein fires displaying the submit button.

My question is how do I unify these individual scripts so that they work as intended with their specific input but does not fire the fadein on the submit button unless all the input values comes back as valid.

Validation Script 1

```
$('#review-username').on('input', function() {
           $('#review-username').addClass('review-invalid');     

        if (!/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/g.test(this.value)) {       
          this.focus();
          return false; 
          this.setCustomValidity('Invalid Characters, Please Use Only AlphaNumeric Characters');
                $('#review-username').removeClass('review-valid'); 
           $('#review-username').addClass('review-invalid');        
        }

          if(this.value.length >= 5) {
            $('#review-submit-button').fadeIn(2250);   
        this.setCustomValidity('');
         $('#review-username').addClass('review-valid');
          $('#review-username').removeClass('review-invalid'); 
          $('#review-submit-button').removeClass('preventclick');
        }


     if(this.value.length < 5) {
$('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);     
                $('#review-username').removeClass('review-valid'); 
           $('#review-username').addClass('review-invalid');
          $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }


                  if(this.value.length > 16) {
                  $('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);     
                $('#review-username').removeClass('review-valid'); 
           $('#review-username').addClass('review-invalid');
          $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }

});
```

Validation Script 2

```
$('#review-jobtitle').on('keyup', function(k) {
    var val = $(this).val();
   if (val.match(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g)) {
       $(this).val(val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/g, ''));
   }
});


$('#review-jobtitle').on('input', function() {   
          $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-valid');  
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('invalid');
     if (!/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/g.test(this.value)) {
         $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-invalid');
        $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-valid');
        }else{           

     if(this.value.length >= 3) {
$('#review-submit-button').fadeIn(2250);
  $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-invalid');
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-valid');
            $('#review-submit-button').removeClass('preventclick');
          }else{
                    $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-valid');
          $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-invalid');
          }
        }

     if(this.value.length < 3) {
$('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
                 $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-invalid');
           $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }else{
          $('#jreview-obtitle').removeClass('review-invalid');
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-valid');
        }

         if(this.value.length > 32) {
         $('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
                 $('#review-jobtitle').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-jobtitle').addClass('review-invalid');
           $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }
});
```

Validation Script 3

```
$('#review-email').on('input', function() {
  $('#review-email').addClass('review-invalid');     
     if(this.value.length >= 6) {

    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
if(this.value.match(mailformat))  

 {  
$('#review-submit-button').fadeIn(2250);
  $('#review-email').removeClass('review-invalid');
 $('#review-email').addClass('review-valid');

 $('#review-submit-button').removeClass('preventclick');

}else{
$('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
  $('#review-email').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-email').addClass('review-invalid');

 $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
}

        }

     if(this.value.length < 6) {
$('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
  $('#review-email').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-email').addClass('invalid');

 $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }
           if(this.value.length > 64) {
           $('#review-submit-button').fadeOut(1250);
  $('#review-email').removeClass('review-valid');
 $('#review-email').addClass('review-invalid');

 $('#review-submit-button').addClass('preventclick');
        }
});
```

Comment: Step 1 use an IDE that can auto-format your code for you. Step 2, just combine all the different event listeners and checks into a single event listener/function and call it once as required.

Comment: So I understand what you mean for step 2 but I am not sure how to implement it.  The submit button id's would not change but when it comes to defining which id to add/remove a given class I am unsure how you would implement a universally usable variable in its place.  Also since the each input validation calls for different types of event listeners, keyup and checking alphanumeric, numeric, or mailformat values, I am unsure how I would go about prioritizing which listeners would need to be fired based upon a the specific need of the input.

Comment: As for step 1 what do you recommend?  I use pspad since it can ftpsync with my lamp server.  Brackets ftp syncing extionsions do not work well for my situation

Comment: Sorry dont know what ide's have ftp syncing support. And Sorry again I was speaking very generally about how to fix the validation issue. Just clearly one validation is running, then another, and the fading is breaking. So... gotta combine some how.

Comment: :: nod ::  They just work as intended and fire off the fade effects without any unifying order, I am unsure as to the next step